# highcharts wordcloud image cloud

Tags: highcharts, word-cloud

Is it possible to display images in highcharts wordcloud when it is a URL of an image?  Instead of displaying the URL itself I want to display the image.

Sample data point in a series

```js
chart.options.series[0].data.push(
    { name: 'test name',
      weight:10,
      color: "#ffffff",
      dataLabel: {
          useHTML: true,
              enabled: true,
              formatter: function() {
              let r = Math.random();
              if (r > 0.5)
                  return '<img src="http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png" style="width: 30px; vertical-align: middle" />';
              else
                  return '<img src="http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/snow.png" style="width: 30px; vertical-align: middle" />';
          }
      },
      className: condition ? 'fade-out' : ''
  });
```

This is what I am trying http://jsfiddle.net/ramakrishnan3/c18xdeLz/1/ a similar way works for parallelcoordinates https://jsfiddle.net/ramakrishnan3/kvfyutqj/10/

Comment: Hi Ramakrishnan Sathya, Unfortunately `wordcloud` is created only to present string values and adapting it to display images would require a lot of customization.

Comment: Hey @ppotaczek Thanks for the reply. But how feasible is it with the current wordcloud version of highcharts? and if it is feasible how to achieve it?

Comment: Hi Ramakrishnan Sathya, it would not be easy to do. You would have to check the `wordcloud` source code: https://code.highcharts.com/modules/wordcloud.src.js and probably overwrite most methods.

Comment: Thanks @ppotaczek. I have to decide how to take this forward. I will keep posted if I am planning to go forward.